# JSP or XHTML? PWC6228: #{...} not allowed in a template text body

Tags: jsp, templates, jsf, el, facelets

I'm trying for the first time to use JSF but I don't understand JSP taglibs for JSF.

Under Eclipse (Indigo) when I create a new JSP file, I can choose between some templates :

- New JavaServer Faces (JSF) Page (html)
- New JavaServer Faces (JSF) Page (xhtml)
- New JavaServer Faces (JSF) Page (xhtml, xml syntax)
- ...

html template uses `<%@ taglib prefix="..." uri="..." %>` whereas xhtml template uses `<html xmlns:...="...">`.

When I choose xhtml template JSF taglib seem to be not supported because when I use `<h:outputText value="#{bean.beanMethod}" />` I received Exception :

> [#|2012-10-04T10:51:45.734+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ApplicationDispatcher[/testjsf] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /b.jsp(14,25) PWC6228: #{...} not allowed in a template text body.
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:81)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:376)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:188)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:755)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:947)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2353)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:499)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1882)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:223)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
>       at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:483)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:300)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

With html template, it works.

So how can I use JSF with xhtml template ?

It works using :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

**AND**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
```

together, but I believed that declaring `xmlns` would replace `<%@ taglib %>` directive ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: ok, it works when I use .xhtml pages instead of .jsp file. Why this behaviour please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP has been [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) as JSF 2.0 view technology almost 3 years ago. Why are you trying to use it?

---

Coming back to your concrete problem:

> PWC6228: #{...} not allowed in a template text body.

This basically means that the `<h:outputText>` has not been parsed by the `FacesServlet` and is thus interpreted as plain template text, including the EL expressions. However, `#{}` in template text as in `<p>#{foo}</p>` is not supported in JSP. It's only supported in its successor Facelets.

The `<h:outputText>` not being parsed by the `FacesServlet` can only mean that the request URL as appears in the browser's address bar didn't match the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in the webapp's `/WEB-INF/web.xml`. This way the `FacesServlet` won't be invoked and all JSF components won't be parsed and be treated as plain text.

Perhaps you've mapped it on `*.xhtml` which explains that Facelets files work fine? You should then open it by `b.xhtml` instead of `b.jsp`.

However, as said, JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0. It doesn't allow you to use all the JSF 2.0 awesomeness such as `<h:head>`, `<f:ajax>`, etc, let alone the [Facelet templating awesomeness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269). Forget JSP and stick to its successor Facelets.

Comment: thank you for this clarification but I don't understand why with .xhtml extension, it's parsed by the FacesServlet since my url-pattern in my web.xml is /faces/* so it should work for none or both, no ? I've seen that GlassFish (my case) and others application servers automaticaly map some pattern (/faces/*, *.jsf) with FacesServlet but in my case, when I remove /faces/* pattern in web.xml, none of the .jsp or .xhtml pages are parsed anymore...I suspect maybe bad configuration...I don't know (PS: previoux comment was incomplete sorry)